# Как плавно уменьшить div по достижению min-width установленной величины

Tags: html, css

**Вопрос:** как при уменьшении браузера уменьшить `div class="three"` с `600px` до `300px`, чтобы этот блок не наезжал на центральный блок?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%
}

.one {
  width: 240px;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  margin-left: 240px;
  margin-right: 600px min-width: 720px;
}

.three {
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    левый блок
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    центральный блок
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    правый блок
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я думаю это вам стоит почитать о медиа-запросах [http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media) Вот тут много примеров резиновой верстки [http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-trekhkolonochnyi-maket](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-trekhkolonochnyi-maket) Вам подойдет Пример 5.27. Макет 5.2

Comment: а чем поможет медиа? Делать попиксельно - бред. Нужна резиновая верстка

Comment: Какой из блоков у вас должен быть фиксированным размером, а какой должен меняться? 
Если и .two и .three меняют свой размер может им стоит width проставить в %?

Comment: @Proshka, так просто посчитайте, сколько у вас ширины должен занимать блок на экране в процентном соотношении, вот и всё. А медиа-запросами можно и резиновость блоку давать, так что ответ более-менее нормальный

Comment: @Proshka И если вы знаете, что просто нужно дать ширину блоку в процентах - зачем лезть на SO за ответом, который вы знаете? Или вы не можете посчитать какой процент 240px,300px 720px, 600px от десктопного формата?

Comment: Посмотрите как работает bootstrap. Они лучшие в адаптивной верстке

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но нужен чистый css без фреймворков

Comment: блок two имеет минимальный фиксированный размер, при уменьшении окна браузера до этого размера, он остается фиксированным, а далее должен уменьшаться правый блок. А правый блок наезжает на центральный. Я так понимаю, что мешает float, который вышибает правый блок из потока и он просто тупо не видит центральный блок

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что бы вы посмотрели как они делают. Не обязательно использовать сам фреймворк. У них до определенного момента идет резина, потом в критических точках через медиа-запросы переключаются стили.

Comment: Попробуйте в HTML-коде поменять .three и .two местами

Comment: не помогает - менял

Comment: убрать float у правого и дать ему margin-left, так как он уже в потоке, а у центрального(он в этом случае опускается вниз) position:absolute; top:0

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону разметки каркаса страницы по флекбокс-сетке - http://paratapok.ru/frontend/5148_css3-flexbox/ или же через медиа-запросы проблему решайте. Вариантов большое количество, но нужно знать что лучше Вам подходит под вашу задачу

Comment: Нужно использовать свойство `overflow`: -  `.wrapper{.........; overflow:hidden;}` чтобы див был заполнен на всю ширину и высоту `float` элементов внутри `wrapper`. И да, для резины, лучше использовать табличный подход либо на `flex-box`. А то у вас прям как хотите не выйдет сделать, либо будет море костылей.

Answer (score -1):

Можно вместо float-элементов решить эту задачу табличным отображением.

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.one{   
    width: 240px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.two{   
    display: table-cell;
    width: 720px;
}

.three{ 
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Тогда третий столбец будет сам подбирать ширину, в зависимости от оставшейся ширины.
Если нет ограничения на поддержку старых версий, то можно сделать сетку с помощью flex https://html5book.ru/css3-flexbox/